# Skipping required field in a list

Tags: list

I have an issue with a list. A user informed me that there are items in the list where a required field is blank.

I have checked the list and could not re-produce the issue. Is it possible to save a list item while skipping the required field?

Answer (score 5):

No, but the field may have been made required after the item was added to the list, or this is a new required field in an older list. Either way, when editing these items (without the required field filled in) it can't be saved unless the required field has a valid entry.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 possible cases I can think of where this might happen. The first and most obvious one is if the list items were created before the column was required. Items without the required fields will continue to exist, but can not be updated without having the required information added I believe.

The other way would be for a document library where a user uses Explorer to upload files. Since Explorer has no way to push the fields (at least that I'm aware of, I could be wrong!) the files are submitted to the library in an un-checked in state. This would cause the file to be in the library and visible to the user that uploaded it without the required field. This file would also not be visible to anyone but the person uploading. You can verify if any documents are in this state by checking the "Manage files which have no checked in version" link in the document library settings.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. The list was created with the required field, but I am not sure if the option was turned-off for a brief period of time, then turned back on. Also, the list is a normal list and not a document library, thus uploading using Explorer is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible in a list connected to Outlook and you enter the list item through Outlook.  Follow these steps:

1. Create a new calendar list.
2. In Sharepoint, Add a new required text column to the calendar list via the ribbon:  Calendar -> List Settings then Columns -> Create Column.  Make sure you tick the 'YES' under `Require that this column contains information` on the create column screen.
3. Connect the calendar to Outlook via the ribbon: Calendar Tools -> Calendar -> Connect to Outlook.
4. In outlook, add a new event to the calendar - just click on a day in the month view and start typing - type the word `Apple`.
5. In outlook initiate the synch with SharePoint - hit F9.
6. Refresh your calendar view in Sharepoint and you will see your new `Apple` event on the same day you added it in Outlook.

This same behavior will happen for other synched list types (tasks, contacts, etc).

Hope this helps find the culprit.  I've found most users prefer to enter items into synched lists via Outlook rather than with the browser into SharePoint and problems like these can occur when they do.

I suggest you see the `Last Modified By` and `Last Modified` Date to see who and when made the update and go ask the user how they did it.